# Unable to format micro SD Card

Tags: partitioning, raspberry-pi, sd-card, mbr, dd

I tried everything, including zeroing out first few sectors, using dd. But these operations have no effect whatsover. I am using Samsung micro SD to SD card adapter to connect to laptop card reader. The microSD card is of Sandisk (16GB class 10).
I have attached sceenshot.[image]

Please help!!!

Comment: The card is dead. Buy a new one.

Comment: Why is it being shown in fdisk then

Comment: The controller has detected a problem and went into read-only mode so data can be recovered without specialized tools. It's a common failure mode for SDs.